# sending mail to mailtrap.io

Tags: email, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1
I made a contact page in my application. So users can send an email. Here I have used mailtrap.io
It works when I have created. I mean there was no problem to send mail to mailtrap.io

But today, when I was checking this again, It shows me this error.

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:
>   Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

I have checked my .env file with mailtrap.io setting. everything is ok. Here is my .env file setting

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=[username]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[password]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Anyone please help me?

Comment: Tip for in the future: don't share your API keys.

Comment: ok. thank you for your advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you have issues with port 25 being blocked by your provider or host.

You can verify this using telnet:

`telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 25`

If you get no response or a timeout, you can not use port 25.

Mailtrap allows you to use 2 other ports, 2525 and 465.

You can verify with telnet if those ports are working.

`telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 2525`

If that connects properly, modify your .env file to use 2525.

---

If you are using `php artisan serve` instead of homestead or something else, be sure to restart after making changes to your .env.

Comment: Thank you For your response. But how I can verify `telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 25`. Can you please tell me details about it.

Comment: You can use telnet just to see if you can open up the connection. If port 25 is blocked, you will not be able to connect. If 2525 is open, it will connect on 2525. That's it basically. Which OS do you use?

Comment: @fokrul I removed your credentials from the OP. Please renew them and use the other credentials in your app.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I was able to use 465 for sending email in a dev-env and updated my ENV file and BAM it worked.!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
MAIL_PORT=465
```

instead of

```
MAIL_PORT=2525
```

like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=your_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your composer by giving

**composer update**

and run your application.