# Laravel Notifications not sending

Tags: php, laravel, email

I set up a contact form which sends an email on completion using Laravel notifications, however it doesn't look like anything is being sent.

ROUTES

```
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@store');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function store()
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:contacts|max:255',
        'message' => 'required|max:2000',
    ]);

    $contact = Contact::create(
        request()->only([
            'name',
            'email',
            'message',
        ])
    );

    User::first()->notify(new SendContactNotification($contact));

    return back()->with('success', 'Thank you, I will be in touch as soon as I can');
}
```

NOTIFICATION

```
protected $contact;


public function __construct($contact)
{
    $this->contact = $contact;
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line($this->contact->name)
                ->line($this->contact->email)
                ->line($this->contact->message);
}
```

I do get the success message when I run it. However, nothing appears in my Mailtrap. Here's the mail section of the sanitised .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='admin@test.com'
MAIL_FROM_NAME='admin'
```

I can't see what I have done wrong. I also tried type hinting the contact in the notification like so:

```
public function __construct(Contact $contact)
{
    $this->contact = $contact;
}
```

That didn't work unfortunately. I also thought it might be something to do with my computer not being set up to send emails using php, but I was under the impression that the env file would take care of that.

The contacts are being stored in the database ok, but no emails are being sent. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Did you set up a mailtrap.io account ?

Comment: type hint the model and what kind of queue driver are u using ?

Comment: When you go into mailtrap and select the mailbox, it will give you the Username and Password for that mailbox.  You are using those in your .env file?  They are different from the username and password you'd use when signing into mailtrap.io.

Comment: @user3158900 yes I just sanitised the file for this question

Comment: @Andrew yes I did

Comment: @Leorent I was using database as the queue driver and I forgot to change it back to sync. I think that may be the answer, I just have to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the port in the env file, I changed it to:

```
MAIL_PORT=465
```

and it worked!

I knew port 2525 wasn't working because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418259/5497241